# Use TypeScript types for function parameter declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it somehow possible to use a type definition (i.e., `IName`) to declare the parameters of a function?

I want to avoid having to replicate function parameter declarations.

I could extract the function declaration into `FullNameFn` but that would not help me a lot with the actual declaration of functions. I would still need to touch multiple places during refactoring.

What I am essentially looking for is the equivalent of defining props (e.g. `props: IName` but for pure functions.

```
// Can I use a type for this?
type IName = {
  firstName:string;
  lastName:string;
}

const fullName = (firstName:string, lastName:string):string => {
  return firstName + lastName
} 


type MyFunctions = {
    fullName: (firstName:string, lastName:string) => string // or FullNameFn
}

type FullNameFn = (firstName:string, lastName:string) => string // Can I use this somehow for function declarations?
```

Comment: You really can't do it this way. Why do you need to? What's wrong with passing an object? Also, how is the order of the parameters decided?

Comment: Function parameters are positional, keys in an object are not

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for exactly; maybe you want a [tuple type in a rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVbBxN)?  If not, could you clarify what you're trying to do? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @caTS is there a better alternative to tech I've described below?

Comment: @caTS Yep, I thought about the positions. Wondered if a "natural order" deconstruction would be possible somehow .. didn't think it is, but gave it a shot with the question

Comment: You can actually do the opposite and turn the tuple into an object... but that is *extremely* fragile and cursed... I don't think you can do this in a *reasonable* way.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the most used way is to use argument descructuring

```
type IName = {
  firstName:string;
  lastName:string;
}
function fullName({firstName, lastName}: IName): string {
   return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
}
```

---

If your type is different for each function, if will not look that good

```
function fullName(
  {firstName, lastName}: { firstName: string, lastName: string }
): string {
   return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
}
```

---

If you have a lot of functions with different arguments if the same set, you may use `Pick` with a global type

```
type AllArgs = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  user: IUser;
}
declare global {
  type Args<K extends (keyof AllArgs)[]> = {
    [k in K]: AllAgrs[K];
  }
}
function fullName(
  {firstName, lastName}: Args<'firstName' | 'lastName'>
): string {
   return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
}
```

then you will have autocompletion and don't need to write types manually.

Comment: If somene knows a better way please tell me, as I'm using this in production